# how to navigate to different page on click of a button in React functional components?

Tags: reactjs

I know we can use  to wrap our components but what is the way to route to a new page on click of a button in React functional components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

React Router has now useHistory hook for functional components:

Docs: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/usehistory

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function HomeButton() {
  let history = useHistory();

  function handleClick() {
    history.push("/home");
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={handleClick}>
      Navigate
    </button>
  );
}

export default HomeButton;
```

Comment: Does history.push makes a async call ? Do I have to handle .then after that?

Comment: @lokeshj its just a way to navigate. It adds your new route to the stack and navigates to that URL. No  Async stuff involved here

Answer (score 0):

for this situations you can code like so :

```
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

const App = ({history , ...rest}) => {

 const changeRoute = () => {
      history.push("/new_route");
   }

  return (
      <div>
         <button onClick={changeRoute}>i will change route</button>
      </div>

   )
}

export default withRouter(App);
```