# How to navigate to new page with React Router by clicking on a three js cube

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, react-router

I'm new to react-router and Javascript in general. I have a MPA with react-router, with animations and shapes using three.js. On my homepage, I have two different three.js cubes, and I want to get it such that when I click on one of those cubes, it navigates to a different page of my site.
I understand that normally with react-router, you would do something like this to create clickable links (this is the HTML code that gets returned by the Homepage js file):

```
<Link id="mouseLink" to='/game-mouse'>Click here</Link>
<Link id="gestureLink" to='/game-gesture'>Click here</Link>
```

However, I want the three.js cubes to serve as the clickable links instead.

In the js file where I created the three.js cubes, I tried to use raycaster and then get the links to work that way, but I understand that this approach doesn't really make sense, because it's not actually making use of react-router and instead just opening a new window:

```
function onDocumentMouseDown(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
    raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children);
    if (intersects[0].object == cube_mouse) {
        //get a link from the userData object
        intersects[0].userData = { URL: "/game-mouse"};
        window.open(intersects[0].object.userData.URL);
        intersects.length = 0;
    } else if (intersects[0].object == cube_gesture) {
        //get a link from the userData object
        intersects[0].userData = { URL: "/game-gesture"};
        window.open(intersects[0].object.userData.URL);
        intersects.length = 0;
    }
};
```

I hope that this makes sense (this is also my first time posting on Stack Overflow, and although I've read many questions on here before, I'm still unsure on how best to present my issue).
Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: Could you elaborate on the problem? What do you mean it doesn't make sense? Your code looks fine to me at a quick glance. What part isn't working, specifically?

Comment: When I click on the cubes, it doesn't actually link to the next page, it just opens a blank tab. Also, doesn't window.open() open a new page instead of actually making use of the react-router?

Comment: I feel like that question has already been answered before: [how to navigate to different page on click of a button in React functional components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60427306/how-to-navigate-to-different-page-on-click-of-a-button-in-react-functional-compo)

Comment: I might be wrong, but I believe that my issue is different, because that answer addresses adding a button to the page using HTML, whereas I want my three.js cube to act as the link to the next page instead.

Comment: Right, I'm not saying copy the code exactly as it is. Change it to suit your needs. Just import `useHistory; let history = new useHistory();` then replace `window.open` in your function with `history.push("/game-mouse");` as suggested in that answer.

Comment: I've tried implementing that answer but it doesn't work in my case. Thanks for your help, though.